# web.py shared variables

Tags: python, web.py

In web.py i need to create a shared variable, for which multiple
threads(requests) can read or write to that variable.

What is the preferred way, for this kind of a situation.

thanks.

Comment: Perhaps give a little more detail on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You should say what kind and size of data that variable will contain, how sensitive is the data, and how often you will write to it and read from it.

Comment: sorry for missing info. read and write is very often to the variable (hundreds in second). so database is not an option. think of an integer.

Comment: memcached is ok. but for my case, running memcached is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is really a web.py question, but we do this sort of thing all the time for process-wide caches (that is, dict caches that are shared by all request threads). We use web.py, but my example below should apply to any multi-threaded Python web server.

hotels.py:

```
cache = {}

def load_cache():
    """Load hotels into {id: data} dict cache."""
    rows = db.select('hotels')
    for row in rows:
        cache[row.id] = row

def get_hotel(hotel_id):
    """Get data for hotel with given ID, or return None if not found."""
    if not cache:
        raise Exception('hotels cache not loaded')
    return cache.get(hotel_id)
```

main.py:

```
import hotels

def main():
    hotels.load_cache()
    start_server()
```

Answer (score 1):

I find lots of code using this container:  web.ctx

like

```
web.ctx.orm = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
web.ctx.session = web.config._session
```

u can init those in a function, then process them:

```
app.add_processor(web.loadhook(init_func))
```

Not sure it works or not for your scenario