# Python global variable not visible in class

Tags: python, null, global

I am currently working on a project for university and I got stuck at a problem.
Since this is my first project using python dont get mad at me.
The code will control a nao-robot via a web-api.
This is a simplified snippet of the code I wrote.

```
Tuersteher = None
class TuersteherModule(ALModule):
    def __init__(self, name):
        ALModule.__init__(self, name)
            #... more init code
    def LearnFace(self, name):
        #... more code to learn the face

WEB_URLS = (
    "/faces/learn", "facesLearn"
)

class facesLearn:
    def POST(self):
        data = web.input(name = "web")
        return Tuersteher.LearnFace(web.websage(data.Name))

def main():
    global Tuersteher
    Tuersteher = TuersteherModule("Tuersteher");

    app = web.application(WEB_URLS, globals())
    app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The Problem is, whenever I try to access the Web-API and the "facesLearn"->POST is called I get the error 
`"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'LearnFace'"`.
I tried some things, but I cant get the global Variabel to work inside of the classes.

Did I miss something? Or is it just a plain mistake somewhere?

Edit: I am using the web.py for the web-server.

Comment: When is `facesLearn.POST` called?

Comment: You don't need the semicolon here: `Tuersteher = TuersteherModule("Tuersteher");`. And "WEB_URLS" should be a list if you don't need keys and values, it should be like that: `WEB_URLS = ["/faces/learn", "faceslearn"]`

Comment: Hard to help without knowing what is the `web` module and how it works. Though as I get it `WEB_URLS` looks like it maps a url to a class name. So it should be a dictionary, and here you have a set (only values, not key-values pairs). So maybe try replacing `{"/faces/learn", "facesLearn"}` with `{"/faces/learn": "facesLearn"}`

Comment: if `web.application` takes a dictionary namespace as the second argument why do you even need to use `globals()`? why can't you just do `{"Tuersteher":TuersteherModule("Tuersteher")}` instead?

Comment: It _looks_ like the object isn't getting instantiated in the first place. Try setting the global to something else, like a number, and printing it, to help locate the issue.

Comment: @Rafael Cardoso: This would be part of the web.application. It is a default python module for creating a simple web server if I read it correctly

Comment: @kjaquier: I made a mistake here, there should be round brackets around the URL. Not quite sure what this construct is supposed to be, but that is how the Documentation of web.application tells me to do it.

Maybe there is a better web-server-library to use?

Comment: @Neokil `(1,2)` makes a *tuple*, `[1,2]` makes a *list*, `{1, 2}` makes a *set*, `{1: 2}` makes a *dictionary* (or dict). These are different kinds of [data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) with different characteristics and behaviours. Tuples are just immutable lists, the others are different beasts (see the links for more details).
After a quick search it seems like you're using [web.py](http://webpy.org/). So check the documentation if not done already, or else edit the question to add this information so that people who know that library can help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512681/how-to-keep-a-variable-value-across-requests-in-web-py

Comment: Maybe add a `global Tuersteher` at the start of the `POST` method.